# How do I use third party JS modules in my Angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently working on an Angular (Angular 4.2.5) project and have been able to add a few third party modules. However, in most cases, if the third party module required me to include a script (like a .js file), I had to add it to my index.html file.

For example, this is what is in my index.html for Bootstrap:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This was also the case for my CSS files but recently found that I could import them into my style.css. Here's an example of what exists in that file for bootstrap as well:

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Now when I look online, I see that I should be able to add the path to the script in question to my angular-cli.json file but every time I have done that, the third party component fails. Only when I add the [script] tag for that component into index.html does it work.

I've tried several online guides but none seem to work. I'm certain I'm missing some minor setting somewhere to ensure that I'm using the angular-cli.json path listed but I can't seem to find it.

Some details in the event you need it:

- @angular/cli: 1.2.0
- node: 6.10.0
- os: win32 x64
- @angular/animations: 4.2.5
- @angular/common: 4.2.5
- @angular/compiler: 4.2.5
- @angular/core: 4.2.5
- @angular/forms: 4.2.5
- @angular/http: 4.2.5
- @angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.7
- @angular/platform-browser: 4.2.5
- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.5
- @angular/router: 4.2.5
- @angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.5

[Edit 07/08/2017]
To be clear, I do have the following in my angular-cli.json but it still doesn't work unless I have it included in my index.html.

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "ang2-crm",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Comment: I did see this tutorial but kept getting an error regarding the .method() statement. I'll try this again tomorrow to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either import them via styles.css or index.html using a link.
Additionally, you can import scripts in your angular-cli.json under `scripts: []`

Comment: Im not bothered leaving it in index.html but the other problem is that I can't point to my node_modules folder, I'm having to get it from a CDN (which I prefer not doing if possible).

Comment: Well, you hit it right on the money.. if you prefer to use the html way using the link tag, you cannot point to "node_modules" as that is in your development environment. If you still want to use the link tag but not use cdn, you can download it and point to it locally (in /lib maybe.) using a CDN is preferred as you'll always get it served in a fast connection. You can point to your node_modules folder in the angular-cli.json under scripts, which will always stay current and needs no maintenance; assuming you keep your package.json up to date.

Comment: Thanks Moshe, I'll use a CDN for now. I did somehow get the pointer in angular-cli.json to work but now I started getting odd behaviour when I compared it to the references found in the scripts area in angular-cli.json. I'm not going to bother fixing it, as you bring up the fact that the CDN is preferred.

Comment: @CSharpNewb, open a new question and I'll be glad to investigate it with you. Please don't forget to choose an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add all scripts in scripts array in .angular-cli.jaon and css files in styles array.

For example if you want to add jquery.min.js.:-

1. Install jquery package by `npm install jquery --save`
2. Then add entry in scripts array as:-

   scripts:[../node-modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js]

Comment: This is what I was trying to do but entering into angular-cli.json under the scripts array doesn't work. I'll modify my post to show what that looks like.

Comment: For bootstrap js to work we should add jquery js before bootstrap js. So please add jquery.min.js entry in scripts array before bootstrap entry.